# Using c# how to retrieve and update thousands of records from a SQL database efficiently

Tags: c#, sql

*Process*

1. I am writing a C# application which will need to retrieve 4 million records(ID) from a SQL table in database A.
2. I then need to use each ID to  select a row of record each from another SQL table in database B.
3. Once I have this row I then need to update another SQL table in database C

*Questions*

1. What’s the most efficient way to retrieve and store the data in Step 1?
   a.  Should I load this in a list string?
   b.  Do you recommend doing batches initially?
2. What the most efficient way to achieve steps 2 and 3

Comment: Are these 3 databases on the same server?

Comment: Step 1 and 3 are on the same server didfferent database(Database A and C). 2 is on a separate DB server

Comment: What is c# application doing?

Comment: exactly what i explained

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the 4M records you're going to want to use a `SqlDataReader` - it only loads one row of data into memory at a time.

```
var cn = new SqlConnection("some connection string");
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM SomeTable", cn);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    var id = reader.GetInt32(0);

    // an so on
}

reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
cn.Close();
```

Now, to handle two and three, I would leverage a `DataTable` for the row you need to retrieve and then a `SqlCommand` on the third database. This means that inside the `reader.Read()` you can get the one row you need by filling a `DataTable` with a `SqlDataAdapter` and the issuing an `ExecNonQuery` against a `SqlCommand` for the `UPDATE` statement.

Another way of writing the above, and it's a bit safer, is to use the `using` statement:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var id = reader.GetInt32(0);

        // an so on
    }
}
```

that will eliminate the need for:

```
reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
```

and so you could also issue that for the `SqlConnection` if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

SQLBulkCopy class might help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx